# Are there ribozymes that cut double strands

Tags: dna, enzymes, rna

the header already says:

Are there any ribozymes known that cut double strands?
A kind of ribozyme equivalent to the Ribonuclease III.

With cut, I mean that the backbone of both strands, forming the double strand, is opened/broken.

Reaction:
one double strand -> two double strands

Comment: Please tell us what research you have done to try to answer this question yourself, and what you have found. Also use standard English if you can: “really cut like” doesn’t cut it, and I find it difficult to see how one can cut something that is already broken. It would be more useful if you specified whether you are referring to RNA or DNA. Context would do no harm either.

Comment: I tried to clarify the answer according to your suggestion. I do not mind if it is RNA or DNA that becomes cut, that is why I did not mention it.

Comment: I think you need to read about ribozymes a little before formulating questions. As they are thought to be relics of an RNA world they are not going to cleave DNA. As dsRNA is not central to modern organisms, even if it had been in early life, it would be unlikely to have survived.

Comment: Could you be more specific? And if the answer is obviously "no", then would you be so kind and answer the question and explain why it is not possible? I still do not understand your question regarding specifying if it is DNA or RNA that becomes cut, as e.g. hammerhead ribozymes cleave or ligate both DNA and RNA.

Comment: My question is not "did it survive" ;) I would also be happy to know about an artificially created ribozyme that cleaves double strands. But dsDNA is central in Biology. As a ribozyme constitutes the core or the Ribosome, I was conjecturing that there might be a ribozyme at the core of an enzyme able to cut double strands.

Comment: Sorry specifying hammerhead ribozymes in this context was wrong. I found this: "A highly conserved ribozyme in the human and in other species is the hammerhead ribozyme. Ribozymes are active in the cleavage or in ligation of RNA and DNA as well as participating in various RNA-processing reactions, such as RNA splicing, the biosynthesis of tRNA and in viral replication.", [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-383864-3.00011-9)

Comment: As far as I am aware from scanning recent reviews, most natural ribozymes act in cis, and none act on DNA. Do you have a reference to the contrary?

Comment: See the one above and [here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1690858/). Admitting that they report that the activity was less for DNA compared to RNA.

Comment: But like mentioned above, I do not mind if you can not find it in Biology. The question is, if it exists at all and if no, if there are reasons why it is not possible to create one.

Comment: The first reference you cited was a book chapter on protein synthesis in which there are 28 references to the ribozyme nature of peptidyl transferase. Please make sure you give correct references before wasting people’s time.

Comment: For completeness, [here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1283908/) is one that states that a hammerhead ribozyme was used to ligate RNA with DNA. Kind of a mixed case.

Comment: "unphysiological" Are you kidding me? I did not ask if it exists in cells. It is a general question. There are people that develop self-replicating ligase ribozymes.

Comment: I just came across a paper where they found a DNAzyme that cleaves RNA https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1283523/

Answer (score -1):

Ribozyms are generally known to have a potential to introduce [strand breaks](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/neuroscience/ribozymes). However, it's indeed a good question whether those may include double strands!

Unfortunately I don't know the answer as it's generally difficult to prove non-existance, but in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00239-012-9503-6), they go as far as to imply that translation needed to evolve due to the lack of helicase activity of ribozymes.

In additional literature for helicase activities (which is generally associated with introduction of double-strand breaks), all [ribozymes with helicase activity](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15017053/) seem to be attached to proteins to be functional. So maybe it's indeed possible, that there are no ribozymes that cut double-strands.

Comment: It is well documented that they make single strand breaks, usually on themselves.

Comment: Yes, on themselves on homologius sequences. By the way, I felt the premise of the question was that it's impossible for rybozymes to introduce double-strand breaks.